# Windows 7 not booting after installation of Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 along side Windows 7 ultimate. But the problem is as soon as I switch on my computer. There is only a blank screen with my TFT screen displaying a message "Out of Range".

Then suddenly Ubuntu loads without showing any option to load Windows 7.

Comment: plz if u have solution post me

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to rebuild Grub to see if that fixes your issue. Try using Super Grub disk. [Super grub disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/)

Answer (score 0):

yes it is not possible when u install Ubuntu after Windows series. you should follow some boot sector aspects like dual boot manager and priority(priority will be like this 1.Win8 then Win 7 after that Ubuntu or unix or Linux). So you should install Win7 then Ubuntu,Beware that those two are not installed in same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+T`.
Type command `sudo update-grub` and then type your password (which will not be shown while typing). Next time you boot up there should be a list of available operating systems, Windows 7 will most likely be the last in the list, Ubuntu being the first.

For more information about Grub or the command `update-grub`, use `man` followed by the command.

Welcome to Linux.